# How to add more data into struct with append or without append?

Tags: go

Well we can use Golang built in append method to add more data into a defined struct. e.g.

```
type aclStruct struct { acl string}

a := []aclStruct{aclStruct{"A"}, aclStruct{"B"}}

a = append(a, aclStruct{"C"})
```

No Doubt it's working. But when I tried without append method it's producing an error. E.g.

What I am trying to do is :

```
a := append(aclStruct{"A"}, aclStruct{"B"}, aclStruct{"C"})
```

Even not sure sure it's a right way for struct because on array it's works fine. Also is there any way of doing this without using of append ?

Any Help??

Comment: `a := []aclStruct{aclStruct{"A"}, aclStruct{"B"}, aclStruct{"C"}}`

Comment: The first argument of `append` should be a slice.

Comment: Thats how append works. It appends elements to a slice. The Tour of Go might explain slices and how to manipulate them in more detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Even not sure sure it's a right way for struct because on array it's works fine.

The [append function](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#append) appends elements to the end of a **slice**.

structs are declared statically. There is simply no way in Go to change their structure to add fields to them at runtime.

If you want a *slice of structs*, which you may use to track multiple representations of the struct, perhaps with different data points, you can build that structure in several ways:

- Using `append`, ensuring the first argument passed is a (possibly empty) slice:

  ```
  a := append([]aclStruct{}, aclStruct{"A"}, ...)
  ```
- Declare the slice variable `a` and pass this to `append`:

  ```
  var a []aclStruct{}
  a = append(a, aclStruct{"A"}, ...)
  ```
- Declaring and initializing the slice with values inline:

  ```
  a := []aclStruct{{"A"}, {"B"}}
  ```

  Note that you don't need to re-specify the concrete type for each slice element, as it can be inferred from the type of the slice)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to declare slice of three elements use: 

`a := []aclStruct{aclStruct{"A"}, aclStruct{"B"}, aclStruct{"C"}}`

`append` should be used to modify currently existing slice (it *appends* to a slice). It is throwing an error, because first argument should be a slice.

if you want to use it:

`var a []aclStruct 
append(a, aclStruct{"A"})`

GoDoc answers the question well:

`func append(slice []Type, elems ...Type) []Type`

The append built-in function appends elements to the end of a slice. If it has sufficient capacity, the destination is resliced to accommodate the new elements. If it does not, a new underlying array will be allocated. Append returns the updated slice. It is therefore necessary to store the result of append, often in the variable holding the slice itself:

`slice = append(slice, elem1, elem2)
slice = append(slice, anotherSlice...)`

Answer (score 0):

first argument of append must be a slice so correct way of doing it is:
`a := append([]aclStruct{aclStruct{"A"}}, aclStruct{"B"}, aclStruct{"C"})`

or

`append([]aclStruct{{"A"}}, aclStruct{"B"}, aclStruct{"C"})`

a way of doing it without append is:

```
a := []aclStruct{aclStruct{"A"}, aclStruct{"B"}}
appendedArray := []aclStruct{aclStruct{"C"}, a...}
```

Comment: The first argument must be a *slice*, not an array. `append` does not accept arrays.

Comment: Also your second example is invalid, you cannot use the `...` syntax in an array or slice literal.